# How can I covert a table to Partition Table?

Tags: oracle11g

Is there any way to do that without reating of all dependent objects

For example `triggers` . so far i have been recreating them .

Is there any way to copy without recreating

Comment: Check out the `dbms_redefinition` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to recreate the table or create new table and rename to original and copy data from original. 
You need to take create of all dependent objects like Triggers, Constraints and Indexes on the original table as well. For example for EMP table to be partitioned:

```
1.  Create a new table New_EMP as partition table. 
2.  Then insert data from original table to new partition table.
3.  Create all indexes and constraints on the new table
4.  Rename the original employees table to something else.
5.  Rename New_EMP to employees.
```